# How to implement a position Sticky on IE

Tags: html, css, sticky, sticky-footer

Here is a position sticky from [this blog](https://medium.com/@elad/css-position-sticky-how-it-really-works-54cd01dc2d46):

https://jsfiddle.net/f29yh51n/

```css
body{color:#fff; font-family:arial; font-weight:bold; font-size:40px; }
.main-container{ max-width:600px; margin:0 auto; border:solid 10px green; padding:10px; margin-top:40px;}
.main-container *{padding:10px;background:#aaa; border:dashed 5px #000;}
.main-container * + *{margin-top:20px;}
.main-header{
  height:50px; background:#aaa;
}
.main-content{
  min-height:1000px;
}

.main-footer{position:-webkit-sticky; position:sticky; bottom:0; border-color:red;}
```

```html
<main class="main-container">
  <header class="main-header">HEADER</header>
  <div class="main-content">MAIN CONTENT</div>
  <footer class="main-footer">FOOTER</footer>
</main>
<br><br><br><br>
```

It means, the footer is sticky on bottom, and when we reach the end of the sticky container (parent), the element will stop in its natural position.

Since IE does not support sticky, it does not work on IE. Is there any tricks to make this work also on IE?

(Not duplicate because i have already tried the suggested workaround from the other question -from 3 years before-) My Current workaround is to use position:fixed on IE, so it behaves like sticky, but then it doesn't stop in its position when scrolled down, but it remains always on bottom of the viewport.

Comment: I can suggest to cound position of your elem and then toggle a position fixed using JS.

Comment: you can [read this](https://css-tricks.com/stickybits-alternative-position-sticky-polyfills/), maybe it help